# Dynamically creating picture on touch - xcode - iphone

Tags: xcode, image, touch, dynamic

Here my current state of affairs: I have a custom scroll view, which contains a custom UIImage view.  The image view already contains a picture.  When the user touches the screen (i have a touch event set up in my UIImage View), I want a clickable marker/picture to be created at that point.

What I have working:  The UIImageView is receiving the touches and storing the CGPoint of the touch in an object.  That object(we will call it the location object) is passed into an object which serves to hold a collection of these location objects(via mutable array).

So to summarize I have a scroll view with a UIImage view in it and an object which contains an array of "location objects"(this object is necessary because i need the locations to be in groups to display in different circumstances).  How do I go about materializing these points to be images on the screen.  I am not married to the technique I am using now.  If there is a better way please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever receive an answer?